# Reading sent data from requests to Socket in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I want to decode the data sent from requests to a
server socket but i don't know what format the data is
is there a way to decode this?

(the output was long its a small part of it)

```
b'\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03,3\x90*\xfe\x8f\xc2\xc2J\xeaCUz6\x91
```

server

```
# server


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
 
port = 80 
 
s.bind(('', port))        
 
s.listen(5)    

while True:
 
  c, addr = s.accept()    
  data = c.recv(5048)
  print ('Got connection from', addr )
  c.send('Thank you for connecting'.encode())

  print(data) 
  c.close()
```

requests

```
import requests

payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

r = requests.get('https://localhost:80', params=payload)
print(r)
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght its a request file i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

On the server site you need to implement https(Hypertext-Transfer-Protokoll-Secure).

Or you use flask.